# DialogFlow Inline Editor never enabled - Google Actions Code Lab

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am trying to run through the Google Actions tutorials to play around with Google Assistant. I've started with the first Code Lab but when I get to the [6th part, step 2](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-1/index.html#5) and try and toggle on the Inline Editor I consistently get:

> Your Google Cloud resources are still being provisioned. Please refresh the page and try again in a few minutes.

I've now been trying to toggle this on for a good two days now, so I think something else is wrong. Something else I could be missing or could check?

Comment: Hmm I saw the same problem on Friday. You can check the Firebase docs on how to deploy locally, and that works. There may be a larger bug.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is because your projects needs to be available in firebase with setup. Follow these steps and check :

1. Open https://console.firebase.google.com and choose your project.
2. On the left menu choose **storage** and click on **get started** button. Follow the steps there.

Once it is done, refresh your dialogflow console and check again.